# Getting Error when convert RDD to DataFrame PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing some study in Apache Spark and I'm facing something really strange. See this code below:

```
ClimateRdd = ClimateRdd.map(lambda x: tuple(x))
print ClimateRdd.first()
```

these commands return to me this line:
`('1743-11-01', '4.3839999999999995', '2.294', '\xc3\x85land')`

Then I move this to a dataFrame like this:

```
schemaDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ClimateRdd, schema)
schemaDf.registerTempTable('globalTemp')
result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT dt FROM globalTemp")
result.show(5)
```

This works perfect and I got this result:

```
+----------+
|        dt|
+----------+
|1743-11-01|
|1743-12-01|
|1744-01-01|
|1744-02-01|
|1744-03-01|
+----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

After I take the query result, and try to run the lines:

```
dates = result.map(lambda x: "Datas: " + x.dt)
print dates.collect()
```

I got an exception of java with this cause: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 4 fields are required while 5 values are provided.`

Well I did a lot of research and I found what was the problem, I changed my first part of code to this:

```
ClimateRdd = ClimateRdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
```

And it worked!

Well the point is, why the first part didn't work? Why I have to manually generate a tuple? Is there a way to create this tuple dynamically?

Comment: It sounds like you have a row in `ClimateRDD` with more than 4 elements. Try doing something like `ClimateRdd.map(lambda x: (1, len(x)).countByValue()` and I expect you'll see rows with 5 elements.

Comment: Try checking if there is any row which contains more than 4 elements.

Comment: Humm, that make complete sense! I will check my dataSet and give you all an answer. Due to if I convert a tuple it will iterate in all data in RDD if it has 4 or more... if a do a manual tuple it didn't happens. I will check the dataset because I didn't know that I had different types of columns. The file is a CSV maybe the name of one type of country.

Comment: Yeah, @santon you were right. There was more than 4 columns in few rows: `defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(1, 5): 2277, (1, 4): 575185})`

Comment: Had the same issue ! Had a blank line and had to remove the blank line by including code to filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the dirty data. The data was not in the default split parameter. The issue was there.

When I made the tuple convertion, that assumes that the structure has 4 fields according with the most part of the data. But at one specific line it wasnt true.

So that is the reason why my dataframe crash in tuple convertion.

Answer (score 0):

That is a little bit weird.
Why do you need tuples ? List work fine with map.

```
ClimateRdd.map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]])
```

Comment: Lists works well to, I know that, My point is, about to setting the tuple manually. But, according @santon comment. Probably my issue is the size of RDD.